# Get-AdUser where mail is not null

Tags: email, powershell, active-directory

I am trying to get a list of all users in AD that have an email (mail attribute). I have this command

```
Get-AdUser -filter * -Properties mail | Select SAMAccountName, mail | Export-CSV -Path $userPath -NoTypeInformation
```

The problem is that I do not know how to limit or filter out users where the email is null/blank. I do not care how complex the script is as it will be part of a much larger powershell script. If the solution is to loop through the CSV that is an option but would prefer something quicker. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this:

```
Get-ADUser -Properties mail -Filter {mail -like '*'}
```

Comment: This returned all users that did not have an email. I replaced it with -like and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: I compared this to the other answer and this is roughly .5 seconds faster on a 10,000 user domain. When talking larger domains that would add up.

Comment: Always use early filtering whenever possible.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
Get-ADUser -Properties mail | where {$_.mail -ne $null} | Select SAMAccountName, mail | Export-CSV -Path $userPath -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: I had to add -filter * since its a required attribute but this worked. Thanks!

Comment: While this is technically a valid answer, you will be pulling all objects from the directory before applying the filter - a most inefficient way to do things.  The answer mjolinor's provided is the better way to handle this task.

Answer (score 1):

The question has already be answered, but for me, the simplest is to rely on LDAP filter syntax. For instance:

```
 Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(mail=*)"
```

The "=*" is a standard LDAP operator:

> * (wildcard)
>
> You use the wildcard operator to represent a value that could be equal to anything. One such situation might be if you wanted to find all objects that have a value for title. e for title. You would then use:
>
> (title=*)

Source [LDAP Query Basics](https://technet.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/aa996205(v=exchg.65).aspx)