# What is the difference when filtering by a null IP address?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

This may very well be a duplicate, as SO warned me, but I didn't see anything in the suggestion box that looked at that resembles my question. This is quite possibly a very easy question also, but I don't really know how to Google this kind of question. What is the difference between:

```
Get-ADComputer -properties ipv4address -filter * | ? ipv4Address -ne $null
```

And:

```
Get-ADComputer -properties ipv4address -filter {ipv4Address -ne $null}
```

For me, the first one works, but the second does not. It errors out saying "$null" hasn't been defined. I thought $null was always ready for use in PowerShell? What gives?

Comment: Not a duplicate. AD user objects and AD Computer objects are different and have different properties that are set different ways.

Comment: @LotPings I don't think this is a duplicate of the linked Q&A, it looks more like more like a Powershell syntax question to me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get-AdUser where mail is not null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27946845/get-aduser-where-mail-is-not-null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/28485.filters-with-powershell-active-directory-module-cmdlets.aspx), there are two ways to restrict the output of an AD cmdlet.
First, you can use the `-LDAPFilter` or `-Filter` parameters to filter the output. Second, you can pipe the results to the `Where-Object` cmdlet.
Where possible, the first method is more efficient for two reasons:

- Filtering is done on the domain controller instead of the local
  client. The domain controller is more likely to be a server class
  computer optimized for queries.
- Filtering results in a smaller resultset sent over the network from
  the domain controller to the client. In contrast, the Where-Object
  cmdlet only filters on the local client after the resultset has been
  sent from the remote computer.

However, when it comes to filtering on Ip4Address, I think the second example does not work because of this:

*There is no attribute of Active Directory computer objects for IP addresses, either IPv4 or IPv6. The `Get-ADComputer` cmdlet retrieves the addresses from DNS, using `[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry($Computer).AddressList`, where $Computer is the name of the computer. This returns an array of IP addresses, both IPv4 and IPv6. But only one (or none) of each is returned by either the `-IPv4Adress` or `-IPv6Address` properties.*

<sup>[Source](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/12056.active-directory-get-adcomputer-default-and-extended-properties.aspx)</sup>

Comment: I was aware of the efficacy of filtering server side vs client side, but it was the second part of your answer that is the answer to my question. So my next question would be, can we somehow use the `GetHostEntry()` method in the filter parameter?

Comment: @Joseph No, I don't thin so because it is a property that is calculated AFTER the results from `Get-ADComputer` are returned.